# Which REST code for a resource which is conditionally available

Tags: rest

I'm making a game where you can start a battle based on a task from a list.

Once you finish a battle (win or lose) the battle state will no longer be available, because there is no battle in progress.

This will be reflected in the API when you GET /battle.

- If there is a battle in progress, you get an object response which reflects the current state of the battle, and a 200 REST code.
- If there is *no* battle in progress, it would tell you you can't do this.

My question is as follows: **What REST code should I use to express that the battle is not currently available.**

Additional:

- I haven't opted for the 404 because my interpretation is for a page which doesn't exist, has probably never existed, and might never exist, rather than a resource which might exist but not right now. I'm prepared to be wrong about my interpretation, though.
- My extremely-basic research indicates a 409 might be suitably indicative, but that implies that the conflict occurs because of the request (such as a PUT), while the nature of my GET is not to affect the data, just report its state.
- I could just detail that no battle is happening in a 200 response, but this feels like a REST code job.
- I realise a REST code might not be the correct way to look at this, if so, please offer insights. Also, anything you think I should read. I'm professionally a front-end developer, so I'm usually consuming the API rather than writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the constraint of using a unique response code to indicate the result, I would opt for an HTTP 204 (No Content).  My rationale is that what you're looking to do is indicate that the resource (your battle) is valid, but there is currently no data available for it.

You could also opt to go HTTP 200 (Ok) and return a payload that indicates the current state, both when a battle is in progress and when it is not.  This is what I'd probably go for, personally, as it helps to normalize the shape of your API for callers.  Instead of callers having to memorize the rules around return code, they receive the same data structure in both scenarios and interpret it to discern the context.  This would also allow you to extend the API with historical data, such as battle stats, after the battle was completed without breaking changes to the API.

I'm thinking something like the following for an in-progress:

```
{
    "Id"         : 1234,
    "InProgress" : true,
    "Battle      :
    {
        "SomeProp"  : "SomeValue",
        "OtherProp" : "OtherValue"
    }
}
```

...and something like the following for one not in-progress:

```
{
    "Id"         : 1234,
    "InProgress" : false,
    "Battle      : null
}
```

I believe both approaches would be considered appropriate RESTful responses.  To me, the choice is personal preference for the API contract that you'd like to offer.